# How do I add route protection by user type to a Laravel web application with React frontend and JWT?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

I'm making a Laravel app that let's teachers administer tests to students. I'm using a React frontend and I'm using JWT to authenticate users. I'd like to protect routes by user type (so for example a teacher can access a page to make tests while a student cannot).

Normally, I'd be able to do something like

```
Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->get('users', function () {
    return auth('api')->user();
});
```

but I'm routing everything to my `welcome.blade.php` and rendering routes using React Router. This is how I'm routing everything:

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

I did this because I noticed I'd get 404 errors when I refreshed a route that wasn't the root (For example if I refreshed the page on /teacher-home I used to get a 404). My question is how do I protect my routes, except for /signin and /signup (want these to be unprotected so anyone can access them), by usertype?

Here is my code for logging in a user:

```
public function login() {
        // get email and password from request
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        // try to auth and get the token using api authentication
        if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
            // if the credentials are wrong we send an unauthorized error in json format
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $token,
            'type' => 'bearer',
            'expires' => auth('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 60, // time to expiration

        ]);
```

Here is my migration for users:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('user_type', ['teacher', 'student']);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is a list of all my routes

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(pathName) => <Redirect to='/teacher-home'/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-question-repo' render={(pathName) => <QuestionRepo path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-home' render={(pathName) => <TeacherHome path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-monitor' render={(pathName) => <TeacherMonitor path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-tests' render={pathName => <TestRepo path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/student-home' component={StudentHome}/>
                        <Route exact path='/student-test' render={() => <StudentTest testName="Normal Curves"/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/edit-question/:item_id' component={EditQuestion}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-tests/new-test' render={(pathName) => <TestForm path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/teacher-tests/edit-test/:test_id' render={(pathName) => <TestForm path={pathName}/>}/>
                        <Route exact path='/signin' component={SignIn}/>
                        <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since react is handing your routing, you shouldn't perform the auth on the server side.

You can use a custom route component and add your auth logic in there. Have a look at the following tutorial:
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: You cannot rely on react alone to protect your information.  You need to protect the route on the backend as well.  Otherwise you can just access the route directly through an http request and get all of the information you want.  That is the whole point of a JWT.  You pass the token to the backend to authenticate your user instead of querying a database every time.  But you absolutely must perform an auth on the server side.  React cannot protect your sensitive information.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my answer, but you definitely need protection on the API routes called by the react components .

Comment: What the question is asking for, however is a way of protecting the react routes. The poster is using a fallback route that just renders the react router view (ie, no data).